# 'dart pub test' can you pass parameters that can be referenced in tests?

Tags: testing, dart

dart/pub v1.10

Can you pass a parameter like 'pub run test -Dkey=value' that can be referenced in a test?

I'd like a strategy to change my test.data.yaml file (say user creds) by passing a parameter.

What is the idiomatic way to accomplish this in dart? shell script?

Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Passing parameters is not supported and as far as I know not planned. I use environment variables to pass parameters.

Comment: is there a hook for a test transformer? I had to add an $exclude transformer to angular to ignore tests... or does not make sense with 'pub run ...'?

Comment: I'm not aware of a hook. What should it provide? Did you ensure the test transformer is the last one in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: I'm not finding a relevant transformer (did look at test sources, no joy).